# Common mistakes with javascript arithmetic

Tags: javascript, math, mistakes

I've ran into several oddities using javascripts floating point arithmetic, but I can never recall them off the top of my head!

**What are some common mistakes when using JavaScript to do math?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The common problems with javascript arithmetic relate to the use of `parseInt`, or the lack of.

Not using radix when converting strings to integers:

```
parseInt("0137"); // 95!
parseInt("0137", 10); // 137
```

Not using `parseInt` at all with arithmetic:

```
var a = "2";
alert(a + 5); // 25
alert(a - 5): // -3!
```

Misunderstanding floating point arithmetic (applies to all languages, not just JS):

```
alert(23 * 1.40 == 32.2); // false, 23 * 1.40 is represented as 32.199999999
alert((23 * 1.40).toFixed(1) == 32.2); // true
```

Calculating currency with floating points may lead to rounding errors, currency values should be treated as integers (multiplied with 100) before processing.

Comment: `Number()` is a suitable replacement for `parseInt(str, 10)`.  Don't forget that `parseInt("09")` (as you might use if you are parsing a time string) actually throws an error.

Comment: parseInt("09") returns 9 in my Firebug.

Answer (score 4):

A common mistake (although with strings & integers, not floats) is forgetting that JavaScript doesn't have strong typing. So you can run into situations where:

```
var myVar = 7;       // 7
myVar += 5;          // 12

var myVar = "7";     // 7
myVar += 5;          // 75

var myVar = "cat";   // cat
myVar += 5;          // cat5
```

All of these are perfectly valid statements in JavaScript.

But it gets weirder, because while "7" and "cat" are both strings, not all strings are treated the same:

```
var myVar = 77;
parseInt(myVar);     // 77

var myVar = "77";
parseInt(myVar);     // 77

var myVar = "cat";
parseInt(myVar);     // NaN

var myVar = "77cat";
parseInt(myVar);     // 77
```

Not to mention that (as @Tatu wrote):

```
var myVar = "077";
parseInt(myVar);     // 63
```